# Click event on drawn shapes

Tags: android, events, graphics

Sorry for my english.

Hello, I write the diagram editor program and I don't know how to add click listener or onTouch event to a drawn shape.

For example, I drawn rectangle and for changing it's color I need click on it.

Thanks for replies

Answer (score 1):

You can attach your drawable onto some type of View (ex: ImageView).  Then you can set a clickListener to the ImageView to detect whenever it's been touched.

Comment: if i have more than one drawables, i will have for each of drawables create an ImageView?

Comment: yup I think that is probably the most straight forward way to do it.